Big CLR exception countsin WMI Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRExceptions
I'm running an ASP.net application (.net framework 4.8). I query WMI object with this command Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRExceptions | ? {$_.name -like "*w3*"} to see how many exceptions are thrown. On some pages, the count increases by 100+ when the page loads. However, when I debugged it with Visual Studio (turned on all the breaks at exceptions), I didn't find any exceptions were thrown. Is there any way I can check what exceptions WMI counted?
